# How to create a local personal folder in Outlook 365 using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, office365

I am new to using VBA but I want to create a local personal folder in Outlook using the following script from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.folders.

I get error from the last line: Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add("My Personal Contacts"):  "Run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)': Cannot create the folder.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
    Sub CreatePersonalContacts() 
     Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
     Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
     Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder 
     Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
     Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) 
     Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add("My Personal Contacts") 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where and when do you run the script? Is it a service application or run on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will successfully run only once. Once the subfolder is created, `Folders.Add` will fail. Try to open the folder first and check if there was an error:

```
On Error Resume next
Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
err.Clear
Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Item("My Personal Contacts")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add("My Personal Contacts")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I am not able to see the folder if it was created... not on the folder panel under Favorites.

Comment: Does the code above work any better?

Comment: Also, what kind of message store is it? Is it IAMP4 by any chance?

Answer (score -1):

To be able to debug the code line-by-line and see how it is working under the hood you may paste it to the VBA editor (see `ThisOutlookSession` module) and run it after setting a breakpoint.

I'd suggest checking whether such folder already exists in the Outlook profile. You can iterate over all subfolders by checking subfolder names, so your may be sure there is no such folder exists before you try to create a new one.

Another possible cause can be the place where and when your code is run. Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You may find a similar errors related to such scenarios, see [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020009): Cannot complete the operation. You are not connected](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/db6e1feb-e099-4f4e-b476-6d1e12c1e1a2/systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-0x80020009-cannot-complete-the-operation-you-are-not?forum=outlookdev).